# Let $S$ be infinite and $A\subset S$ be finite. Prove that $|S| = |S\setminus A|$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, set-theory

Let $S$ be infinite and $A\subset S$ be finite. Prove that $|S| = |S\setminus A|$

---

**Given Solution**

Let $A = \{s_1,\ldots s_n\}$. Since $S$ is infinite the set $S\setminus A$ is non-empty. Pick any
$s_{n+1}\in S\setminus A = S\setminus \{s_1,\dots, s_n\}$. Next, since $S\setminus \{s_1,\dots , s_{n+1}\}\neq\emptyset$  we can choose $s_{n+2}\in S\setminus \{s_1,\ldots, s_{n+1}\}$. Proceeding by induction we can construct $s_{m+1}\in S\setminus \{s_1,\dots, s_m\}$
for any $m\geq n$.

Now define $f : S\to S\setminus A$ by the formula $f (s_i) = s_{i+n}$ for any $i$ and $f (x) = x$
if  $x\in S\setminus \{s_1, s_2,\ldots\}$. By construction, $f$ is 1-1 and onto.

---

Similar but concrete example I could fully understand $(0,1)\sim [0,1]$ by

$$f(x) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{1}{10} & \text{if } x = 0, \\
\frac{1}{100} & \text{if } x =1.\\
\frac{1}{10^{n+2}} & \text{if } x=\frac{1}{10^n}.\\
x, & \text{otherwise }
\end{cases}$$

---

The subtle difference here is that $[0,1]$ is uncountably infinite, so we can split out a infinite sequence (countable) to map recursively.  However, in the previous question, we only know the set is infinite, not sure if it is countable or not, how does it function define like below

$f : S\to S\setminus A$ by the formula $f (s_i) = s_{i+n}$ for any $i$ and $f (x) = x$
if  $x\in S\setminus \{s_1, s_2,\ldots\}$.

I try to let $S=\mathbb{N}$ and $A=\{1,\ldots,10\}$, it is not injective. Moreover, how come the finite $A$ becomes infinite as $x\in S\setminus \{s_1,s_2,\ldots\}$ all of sudden

Answer (score 0):

if you let $S=\mathbb{N}$ and $A=\{1,;\ldots, 10\}$.

When we can just let $f:S \to S \setminus A$ be $f(x)=x+10$. Clearly the function $f$ is bijective.

The proof does not make use of countability.

Comment: What about another part in the proof that $f(x)=x$ if $x\in S\setminus \{s_1,s_2,\ldots\}$

Comment: Note that even though $S \setminus \{s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_m\}\ne \emptyset$, we have  $S \setminus \{s_1, s_2, \ldots\}$ is empty for my $f$.

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove that there exists $f:S\to S\setminus A$ that is al least injective. 
Because $A\subset S$ and $A$ is finite we enumerate the elements as $a_n$ with $n\leq|A|$. Even though $S$ is infinite we can still enumerate it's elements in an arbitrary way thanks to the Axiom of Choice. For example let $s_k\in S$ and $k\leq |S|$ such that $$\forall s_{i},s_j,\,i\neq j\, s_i\neq s_j$$.
Which means that we can (somehow) enumerate them and they are all different if they have different indices.
Because of this we can now put all $A$s elements upfront. Let's now finally define $f$ as it follows:
$$f(s_k)=s_h \text{ such that }h=min\{\text{index greater than k+1}\,|\,s_h\notin A\}$$
This function is injective because if will skip all $A$s elements and then is just a bijection from $S\setminus A$ to itself. We showed that $$|S|\leq |S\setminus A|$$ which concludes